# scala: How to handle Option in a functional way

Tags: scala

I am new to scala so my question could be completely stupid. If I have an existing method like below. I am adding these 4 lines to the method. Is there a better way to handle the option value?

```
def processData(input: String, dataMap: Map[String, String]): Option[String] = {

   //4 lines I am adding.
   val data: Option[String] = dataMap.get(input)
   if (data.isEmpty) {
     return None
   }

   //how to avoid this line
   val dataValue = data.get

   //20-25 lines of code in here with bunch of pattern matching case statements
   cleanData(dataValue)
   doSomethingElse("apple", dataValue, "test")
}
```

Essentially I want to avoid having to do "data.get" in the below code. Somehow feels wrong to call that. I could wrote this differently using pattern matching as below. But the 20-25 lines of code have bunch of case statements and I dont want to create another layer on top of them.

```
def processData(input: String, dataMap: Map[String, String]): Option[String] = {

 dataMap.get(input) match {

   case Some(dataValue) => {
   //20-25 lines of code in here with bunch of pattern matching case statements
    cleanData(dataValue)
    doSomethingElse("apple", dataValue, "test")
  }
   case None => None
 }
```

}

Any ideas?

Comment: Keep in mind that Scala adopted 2 space indentation because highly nested code isn't seen as inherently bad in it.

Answer (score 6):

Actually your second way is of functional style, but for conciseness you can use one of the `Option` higher order functions:

```
  def processData(input: String, dataMap: Map[String, String]): Option[String] = 
    dataMap.get(input).map { dataValue =>
      cleanData(dataValue)
      doSomethingElse("apple", dataValue, "test")
    }
```

You can even avoid dots and parentheses :

```
  def processData(input: String, dataMap: Map[String, String]): Option[String] = 
    dataMap get input map { dataValue =>
      cleanData(dataValue)
      doSomethingElse("apple", dataValue, "test")
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, your pattern matching **is the functional way** of handling Option.

If it bothers you that you have these nested case statements, why not refactor them, pull these 20-25 lines out into a new method and call this method in the `case Some(_)` body?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe

```
for (dataValue <- dataMap.get(input)) yield {
  cleanData(dataValue)
  doSomethingElse("apple", dataValue, "test")
}
```